# Importing value from txt-file to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, datatool, import

I want to import a value form an txt-File and use it in tikz. But for some reason this is not working (line 25). I was not able to find a workaround like the \protect-command which works for \caption or \section.

The error message is:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \tikz@scan@point@coordinate.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{text1.txt}
per = 10
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{ = }
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{para}{text1.txt}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\datapar}[1]{\DTLfetch{para}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}

\newcommand{\test}{10} % alternative implementation (for testing)

\begin{document}
insert value form text1.txt: \datapar{per}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (\datapar{per},0) -- (4,0); %value from text1.txt in tikz (not working)
        \draw (\test,0) -- (4,0); % same value from different variable is no problem.
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{caption is working, too: \protect\datapar{per}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `\DTLfetch` retrieves and prints the value. But you do not want to print it, you want to use it for a computation. With pgf you do not need to create an expandable variant, it suffices to declare a function that retrieves the value and stores it into `\pgfmathresult`. I called the function `datapar` to match the name of your macro, but obviously you can create much more elaborate functions of this type.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{text1.txt}
per = 10
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{ = }
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{para}{text1.txt}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\datapar}[1]{\DTLfetch{para}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{datapar}{1}{%
\edtlgetrowforvalue{para}{\dtlcolumnindex{para}{thekey}}{#1}%
\dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\pgfmathresult}{\dtlcolumnindex{para}{thevalue}}%
}
\newcommand{\test}{10} % alternative implementation (for testing)
%\show\DTLfetch
\begin{document}
insert value form text1.txt: \datapar{per}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw ({datapar("per")},0) -- (4,0); %value from text1.txt in tikz (not working)
        \draw[red,dashed] (\test,0) -- (4,0); % same value from different variable is no problem.
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{caption is working, too: \protect\datapar{per}}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added the second line red and dashed to be able to confirm that both lines have the same start and end points, as they should.